# Prevent some programs from using VPN on Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, vpn

Problem: I have created a VPN and it works flawlessly.  However, I want to prevent certain programs, such as FTP and IRC, from using the VPN.

In other words I want everything except FTP and IRC to go through the VPN. FTP and IRC should continue to use my original home connection.

Operating system Mac, OSX 10.10

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please edit your [question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) to include what research you've done on your own in attempt to answer your own question.  Tell us what you've tried so far and specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: I have tried using virtual desktop and proxy through there and leave computer alone, but its not what I want. I want to be able to limit VPN access with using a virtual desktop to get to and outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restrict the movements (internet) off applications on Mac. Meaning if I want to use VPN either all my programs go through it, or I use virtual box and VPN through the virtual box.